# LaTeX: how to change SOME figure's titles from Figure to Code?

Tags: latex, title, figure, caption

My manuscript uses `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` to both images and code fragments.

However, I want that code fragments are titled "Code 1. ..." and not "Figure 1. ...", while the pictures are still titled "Figure 1. ...".

What I can find is only how to change figure titles for the whole document.

Comment: Maybe rather use the [listings](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings?lang=en) package for code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the float package to create new float types:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}

\newfloat{Code}{htbp}{loc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\caption{a figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{Code}[htbp]
\caption{some code}
\end{Code}
    
\end{document}
```

(although the result would be better if instead of images, you'd use a proper source code package to include the code, e.g. `listings`  or `minted`)

Comment: That is working, but... my paper is in Russian, so I need a Russian title, like "Код 1. ...", which I cannot do like \newfloat{Код}. How do I change that? For pictures, figure title is in Russian: "Рис. 1. ..."

Comment: @Ramayasket Can you test `\floatname{Code}{Код}`? If this does not help, please add a compilable [mre] to your question that shows how you setup the fonts etc.